# EF Code First makes One-To-One instead of Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-migrations

I noticed strange problem with my EF Code First fluent API mapping. I wanted to make two many-to-many relationships, but EF doesn't seem to see my overloaded OnModelCreating function, make one table by its own convention and another one [converts to One-To-One relation](https://puu.sh/vxKXW/5f6d10e7b8.png).

Models:

```
public partial class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
        ParentTasks = new HashSet<Task>();
        ChildTasks = new HashSet<Task>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte Progress { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Deadline { get; set; }

    //Foreign keys
    public int ListId { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    public TodoList List { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Task> ParentTasks { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Task> ChildTasks { get; set; }
}

public partial class TodoList
{
    public TodoList()
    {
        Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
        Users = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string ListName { get; set; }

    //Foreign keys
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    public ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// List of the users that have this list shared.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        TodoLists = new HashSet<TodoList>();
    }
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at most {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at most {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1024*1024, ErrorMessage = "Max size: 1MB")]
    public byte[] Avatar { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties

    /// <summary>
    /// List of the shared todo lists with specific user.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<TodoList> TodoLists { get; set; }
}
```

And the DbContext:

```
public class TodoDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TodoDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TodoList> TodoLists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
            .HasMany<Task>(t => t.ParentTasks)
            .WithMany(t => t.ChildTasks)
            .Map(m =>
                m.MapLeftKey("TaskID")
                .MapRightKey("ParentID")
                .ToTable("TaskCorrelations")
            );

        modelBuilder.Entity<TodoList>()
            .HasMany<ApplicationUser>(t => t.Users)
            .WithMany(a => a.TodoLists)
            .Map(m =>
                m.MapLeftKey("ListID")
                .MapRightKey("UserID")
                .ToTable("SharedTodoLists"));
    }

    public static TodoDbContext Create()
    {
        return new TodoDbContext();
    }
}
```

Do I need to manually "run" this context? EF migration system doesn't even see the changes in my DbContext.

**edit**: Those are things I did with config:

- Enable-Migrations
- first added the migration manually, but it didn't seem to work, so I turned automatic migrations on
- AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
- AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;

Comment: Are you using automatic migrations?

Comment: Yes, I did it with automatic migration. Also tried with Add-Migration + Update-Database manually, though.

Comment: Did it also create a junk table "SharedTodoLists" in the database (I can't see it in the screentshot)?

Comment: @IvanStoev it doesn't. It seems like it didn't run, after all. The only table created (except from models) is TaskTasks -> so Many-to-Many relation by default EF convention.

Comment: Hmm, it should though (and usually does) take into account your `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: Do I need to set it up somehow except the way I showed up so far in the code? It seems quite strange, and I have quite a big problems with these migrations. Thought I've skipped some kind of step during configuration.

Also, if that will help anyhow - also doesn't seem to work on local DB - that's where it's usually deployed by default.

Comment: All I can do is to confirm that copy/pasting your model and configuration in my EF test environment produced exactly what is expected. My test also was with local DB.

Comment: Should I do Update-Database -target:0 to reset it and try to migrate it one more time, then?

Also, did it make Many-to-Many relation like it supposed to? I mean, the SharedTodoLists table and the FKs for it.

Comment: It did.(5 tables, 2 being many-to-many link tables). Btw, I don't see something like `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<....` in your `DbContext` constructor which I think is necessary for automatic migrations (plus enabling them in the custom `Configuration` class).

Comment: Oh, I didn't. That also may be the problem. Also, can I use two different contexts (like, default ApplicationDbContext together with my TodoDbContext)? I added comment about that to the @nocodename answer below. Or should I keep everything in one class (but that doesn't seem good)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure migrations like this:

**TodoDbContext**

```
public class TodoDbContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    /...
}
```

**Configuration**

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationConfiguration<TodoDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected override void Seed(TodoDbContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I use both default ApplicationDbContext and my TodoContext at once? I didn't even think that may be a problem. Or should I just keep everything in default Context?

Comment: Then just derive your `TodoDbContext` from `ApplicationDbContext`. EF should track changes inside both contexts then as long as `Configuration` targets the `TodoDbContext`. I've updated the answer.